# The resource cannot be found error - running on my local machine, not IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Every time I try to launch my project, I keep getting this error message.

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /

I tried setting the web page as my start page and I tried changing the authentication mode to

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>

<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

but I am getting the slightly different

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/Shared/default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

how do I get this to work?

Comment: I get this error whenever I open a certain existing mvc project, create a new and empty mvc project, but not when I create a new and non-empty mvc project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC2 won't work. Getting "The resource cannot be found." error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506830/asp-net-mvc2-wont-work-getting-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is try to build the application again and see if you get any errors that way. If you do not get any errors them another thing you could try is moving where your application is run from as IIRC visual studios can be a bit weird when working from a shared directory (I am guessing from the name that it is on a network location if it is not them ignore that last suggestion)

The only other thing i can think of is that your web config file may have gotten messed up a bit somehow. If there are no major changes from the standard web config file produced by Visual studios then I say create a new asp project and copy over the newly created web config to your current project

Hope this helps